# A System of Nonlinear Equations with a norm constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the following equations

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
x=\frac{1}{n}\|\mathrm v-y1_n\|_1\\ 
y=\frac{1}{n}(\mathrm v^T 1_n-x1_n^T sign(\mathrm v-y1_n))\\ 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

where $x\in R^{+}$, $y\in R$, $\mathrm v \in R^n$, and $1_n$  denotes a vector of dimension $n$ with entries all equal to one. Also $sign(\mathrm w)$ returns a vector of the same size of its argument containing the sign of vector's elements.

I have tried an iterative approach $\left\{  \begin{array}{} x_{k+1}=\frac{1}{n}\|\mathrm v-y_k1_n\|_1\\  y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{n}(\mathrm v^T 1_n-x_k1_n^T sign(\mathrm v-y_k1_n))\\  \end{array} \right.$ to solve this system. However, depending on initial values $x_0$ and $y_0$, solutions may be converged to different values.

How can I find the number of possible solutions to the above system? and is it possible to have these solutions in a closed-form?

Comment: What have you tried, for example with $n=2$ ? Besides, could you give some indication about the origin of the problem ?

Comment: I tried to solve it for general $n$ which is in range 50~100 in my problem. Due to sign function I could not find the solution by substituting of one equation into another. I should mention that the $l_1$ norm in first equation can be written as $(\mathrm v-y1_n)^T.sign(\mathrm v-y1_n)$.

Comment: Have you tried if a recurrence approach $\left\{ 
\begin{array}{}
x_{k+1}=\frac{1}{n}\|\mathrm v-y_k1_n\|_1\\ 
y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{n}(\mathrm v^T 1_n-x-k1_n^T sign(\mathrm v-y_k1_n))\\ 
\end{array}
\right.$ would yield convergence ?

Comment: yes, I have tried iterative manner and it is converged. But I would like to know  whether is it possible to get a closed form solutions.

Comment: The fact that 1) you use 1-norm instead of 2-norm 2) the sign operator is used make me pessimistic about a closed-form solution, but maybe, I am wrong...